# Two floating columns with background

Tags: html, css

Im banging my head against the wall on this one, for couple of hours now.
I have a layout with two columns:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/23sumbs.jpg

First is 340 px wide, second is 860px as seen on picture.

Problem i have are the backgrounds for the left and right colum.. they go for the left column all the way to the left, and for the right column all the way to the right side of the screen. How can i achieve this?

Ahy help will do..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if it is simply about plain colors then a background-image (or css gradient) and shadows on each sides should be fine:

```css
body>div {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, darkgray 320px, gray 320px);
  width:1200px;
  margin:auto;
  box-shadow:-1000px 0  darkgray, 1000px 0 gray;
  border:solid;
}
body>div>div:first-child {
  float:left;
  width:320px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

a codepen to play with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoVGaa